# How to work with this time series data for crop prediction?

Tags: python, time-series

I am trying to make a model that analyzes recommended crop types for a certain area.

For my ROI I already have the historical data for each pixel from 2005 to 2009, that includes:

1. Crop type that was produced in that pixel ( 1 for each year )
2. Productivity for each type of crop in my ROI
3. Various weather indicators per year per pixel (surface temperature, rains, temperature, soil properties, etc.

So i have many tables, they all look something like this (these are examples, not actual values)

table 1 (how crops evolved over the years)

[image]

Table 2 (this one and many more on how weather evolved over the years)

[image]

Now I am trying to put everything together to make a model that can explain weather changes that lead to a change on crop type and also that gives a suggestion for the best crop type to use according to actual weather conditions.

I'm completely lost on how to even merge all the information, where should I start looking for an answer?

Comment: you have to make assumptions here. if you assume that the crop change was a positive change, and that it lead to a better outcome then you can model that. However, this may not be true, since changing a crop can be the result of trial and error. Overall, your question is too wide to answer.

Comment: Thank you Eugen. I dont know  if  i can assume  positive  or negative change because i cant predict the productivity of another crop. I just  have  the one that  was actually used. How will you narrow the question? I was thinking on making one table for each  pixel ( or ar least for dome pixels) then it would  have the tipical structure. Does that make any sense  to you? Do i lost information over pixel interaction?

Comment: I recommend also including the previous few years' crop type and info.  Inputs: soil type, year_0_crop_type, year_1_crop_type ... year_0_yield, year_1_yield... year_0_avg_temp... year_n_crop_type.... Output: year_n_yield.  You'll have to one-hot encode your categorical variables.  Try building a [linear model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) for starters, and see how it goes.

Comment: I hope ROI means return on investment. I have made some proposal as an answer, have a look

Comment: I think it means "region of interest"

Comment: ok, @Dani San, have you looked at my suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two objectives here, let's address them one by one.

`also that gives a suggestion for the best crop type`

For this, we make the assumption that the historical choice for a particular crop was the best one. If not, then you should include only those data points that have an ROI above some threshold defined by you.

Approach 1) Simple feed-forward neural net. Your input  [surface temperature, rains, temperature, soil properties, etc], your output: [crop type]. By this, we model it as a classification problem.

If you want to include weather data over long time, then modify your input [(surface temperature, rains, temperature, soil properties, etc) @ t1, (surface temperature, rains, temperature, soil properties, etc) @ t2, etc] . Your output [crop type @ tn] where n is your current time.

Approach 2) if you want to preserve the spatial dimension and that you think nearby pixel data is also important for the prediction, then encode that pixel info into your input too. Otherwise, you can use some spatio-temporal model like described here https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5955-convolutional-lstm-network-a-machine-learning-approach-for-precipitation-nowcasting

Your other question `weather changes that lead to a change on crop type`

This can modelled as a binary classification problem where you want to predict given an input weather condition the output (change or no change in crop). Your input:  [surface temperature, rains, temperature, soil properties, etc], your output: [change or no change]

There are many ways you can solve this second question starting from a simple logistic regression, svms or use more powerful deep learning models depending on the data you have.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this was very helpful. I was kind of lost and this gives me a point on how to start working with it. Ill try it and see where i can get.